# No content displays when app runs on recyclerViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, okhttp

This is the code I am Using.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ArrayList<String> ImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> ImageNames = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> ImageDesc = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initImages();

    }

   private void initImages(){

       final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

       final Request request = new Request.Builder()
               .url("http://url.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed")
               .build();

       @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak") AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
           private static final String TAG = "SlideFragment";
           @Override
           protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
               try {
                   Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                   if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                       Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: REsponse Un Successfull - 56");
                       return null;

                   }
                   String Data =  response.body().string();
                   response.body().close();
                   return Data;
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Exceptione on line63");
                   return null;
               }

           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(String Data) {

               super.onPostExecute(Data);
               if (Data != null) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: line72");
                   try {
                       JSONArray json = new JSONArray(Data);
                       for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                           JSONObject post = json.getJSONObject(i);
                           String title = post.getJSONObject("title").getString("rendered");
                           String description = post.getJSONObject("content").getString("rendered");
                           String imgURL = post.getJSONObject("_embedded").getJSONArray("wp:featuredmedia").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("media_details").getString("file");
                           String imagUrl = "http://url.in/wp-content/uploads/" + imgURL;
                           ImageNames.add(title);
                           ImageDesc.add(description);
                           ImageUrls.add(imagUrl);
                           Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: " + ImageNames);
                           }

                   }catch(JSONException j){
                       j.printStackTrace();
                       Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: on line 121");
                   }
               }
           }
       };
       asyncTask.execute();
    initRecycler();

   }
   private void initRecycler(){

       RecyclerViewPager mRecyclerView = (RecyclerViewPager) findViewById(R.id.list);

// setLayoutManager like normal RecyclerView, you do not need to change any thing.
       LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
       mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout);

//set adapter
//You just need to implement ViewPageAdapter by yourself like a normal RecyclerView.Adpater.
       RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ImageUrls, ImageNames, ImageDesc, this);
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

   }
}
```

I have run the same code with local data i..e the ArrayList with hardcoded data. It works. But If I try with API data It shows Nothing. I have checked the ArrayList with logging. It is fine.

I don't know where I am Wrong.

> UPDATE

Thanks to @sonhnLab. In the code I have removed `initRecycler();` from `initImages();` and added to `onPostExecute();`. That worked.

Comment: You should create a callback and call it in function onPostExecute after receiving all data. Then call initRecycler() in callback.

Comment: Yeah, It worked. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :D

Comment: @SonhnLab Please write the answer so that the op can accept the answer and have it documented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the asynchronous nature of Asynctask, the following line: "initRecycler();" doesn't necessarily gets called after completion of the network request hence no content. Remember, any task that depends on the asynchronous response needs to be implemented inside response method, in this case inside onPostExecute().

Answer (score 1):

With the Help of [sonhnlab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7090048/sonhnlab) I have successfully got the desired output.

I have made this `initRecycler();` call into `onPostExecute()` call. so when the information is ready from the API call it initiates the Recycler.

I have Updating the Code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should call initRecyler() onPostExecute when async task is completed